# C#, calculate position of point by position and distance values of other points

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I have a `struct` with these values:

```
struct Point {
    public float x;
    public float y;
}
```

And I have three variables of this structure `point1`, `point2` and `point3`.

I need to calculate position of `point4` and only things that I have is the distances of `point4` from each of these points.

Is it possible to calculate position of point only by position of other three points with distances?

Comment: This sounds like homework?

Comment: May be this answer will help you with your calculation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370356/calculate-coordinates-of-a-point-with-given-distances-to-two-other-points

Comment: Take a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211765/finding-the-coordinates-of-an-unknown-point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course its possible. This is simple geometry.

1. Take point `P1`. Somewhere at distance `d` is `P4`.

   What geometrical shape in 2D defines all points at a given distance from another point? Yup, a circle. Lets draw a circle centered in `P1` with radius equal to the distance between `P1` and `P4`.
2. Now take `P2` and do the same with the appropiate distance. Now, what can happen? Well, there are 2 possibilities:

   - Circles around `P1` and `P2` don't intersect: the problem has no solution, you have finished.
   - Circles around `P1` and `P2` have one (are tangent) or two intersection points.
3. Now take the third point `P3` and again draw a circle with the appropiate radius. Two things can happen again:

   - New circle intersects with previous drawn circles in one of the intersection points previously identified; you found your solution, the common intersection point of all three circles is `P4`.
   - New circle does not intersect with previous drawn circles in any of the intersection points previsouly identified; problem has no solution.

Now that the algorithm for solving the code is clear, you "just" need to implement it. Consider creating types that represent points and circles and methods that intersect circles:

```
class Point
{
    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }
    ...
}

class Circle
{
    public Point Center { get; }
    public double Radius { get; }
    ....
    public static IEnumerable<Point> Interstect(Circle first, Circle second) { ... }
}
```

When you have coded something and stumbled upon unsurmountable odds you can post another question here asking for help solving more precisely defined problems you may be encountering. No one is just going to code your (home)work for you.

I do note that the solution is not mathematically trivial, but if you can't solve the mathematical problem  to begin with then you have no business trying to code a solution.